# Facebook JS SDK FB.Data.Query & query.wait methods not returning results for some FQL queries

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm playing around with Facebook's JS SDK and FQL, trying to get results for some queries, the first two queries I try (fql) work perfectly fine, the latter half don't work.

If I call FB.getAccessToken() and retrieve my current session's access token, then use that access token to ping the FQL endpoint it works:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+name,+is_app_user+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+ 504405294)&access_token=#############&format=json
```

Anyone know why it doesn't work when using the FB JS SDK?

```
    //  var fql = 'SELECT pic_square, uid FROM user WHERE uid = 504405294 OR uid = 100002624783324 OR uid = 1634269784 OR uid = 100002917463525';
        var fql = 'SELECT name, pic_square, sex FROM user WHERE uid = 100002624783324';
    //  var fql = 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())'; //ORDER BY is_app_user DESC LIMIT 0, 1000';
    //  var fql = 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 504405294';

        console.log(fql);

        var query = FB.Data.query(fql);
        query.wait(function(rows){
            console.log(rows);

        });
```

**Edit**

To be a little more clear, the console.log(rows); call in .wait() never happens. The console is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you must write some like this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(user) {   

      this.query =  FB.Data.query("SELECT name, pic_square, sex FROM user WHERE uid =me()", user.id);

                this.query.wait(function(rows) {

                   console.log(rows); 

                 });


            });
```

Comment: I wrote this question a long time ago but you might want to make sure you're not using FB.Data.query and query.wait --  those are deprecated and slated to be removed soon

Comment: @CaseyFlynn what can I use instead?